# URLWithString"http://google.com" VS URLWithString"http://apple.com"

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

I have the following code.

```
NSURL *serverUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *stringFromStream = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:serverUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"string is %@ error is %@", stringFromStream, error);
```

This piece of code produce the following errors

```
2012-05-29 11:57:46.914 [2221:f803] string is (null) error is Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)" UserInfo=0x6a36c60 {NSURL=http://google.com, NSStringEncoding=4}
```

But if I change URL to

```
NSURL *serverUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"];
```

I would work perfectly.

Comment: The exact same code works in my mac :O

Answer (score 0):

The encoding of the content is probably not UTF-8.  Try this method instead:

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url
               usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc
                      error:(NSError **)error;
```

(You'll have to `release` the `NSString` when you're finished with it).

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).